# Complex Object mapping using Automapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda, automapper

I'm trying to use auto mapper to achieve the below code.

```
List<VlaListView> vlaVmList = new List<VlaListView>();
var vlaCollectionList = vlaCollection.ToList(); //database populate list

foreach (var vla in vlaCollectionList)
{
    VlaListView vlaVm = new VlaListView();
    vlaVm.VlaId = vla.VlaId;
    vlaVm.UserName = vla.UserName;
    vlaVm.DateOut = vla.DateOut.ToShortDateString();
    vlaVm.ReturnDate = vla.ReturnDate.ToShortDateString();
    vlaVm.Status = vla.Status;

    string regnumbers = string.Empty;

    foreach (var vehicle in vla.Vehicles)
    {
        regnumbers += vehicle.RegistrationNumber + ", ";
    }

    regnumbers = regnumbers.Remove(regnumbers.Length - 2);
    vlaVm.RegistrationNumbers = regnumbers;

    vlaVmList.Add(vlaVm);
}
```

I get all the values to map apart from the registration numbers which can have a list of vehicles with registration numbers. I'm trying to loop and get the values of `vla.vehicles.RegistrationNumber`, concatenate and save the results to my view model field. My Automapper code is below

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(config =>
{
    config.CreateMap<Vla, VlaListView>()
        .ForMember(x => x.DateOut, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.DateOut.ToShortDateString()))
        .ForMember(x => x.ReturnDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ReturnDate.ToShortDateString()))

        // this is the ForMember I can't work out, I can't get the values of the registration numbers
        .ForMember(x => x.RegistrationNumbers, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Vehicles.Select(v => string.Join(", ", v.RegistrationNumber))));
});
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: The use hngnNotation and the mixing of `vla` and `val` makes this very unreadable.

Comment: Sorry I have edited the typo on valCollectionList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, but `string.Join` should be outside the `Select` (currently it compiles only because `string` is `IEnumerable<char>`, thus hitting [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx), and the results is some strange list of strings with comma concatenated chars):

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.RegistrationNumbers, opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>
    string.Join(", ", src.Vehicles.Select(v => v.RegistrationNumber))));
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ivan and thank you for the clear explanation I have marked this as the answer